# Generating a dynamic proxy/decorator/encapsulator in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public function func1():void{}
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    public override function func1():void{
        trace("middleman");
        base.func1();
    }
}
```

I know of the Proxy class, but what I want to achieve is something like

```
var instance:ClassA = new ClassA();
instance = Modifier.messWith(instance); //returns instance with ClassB functionality, without ClassB being defined at compile time
```

The class count I want to give the extra functionality is high, and I do not want to spend all the time in the world writing an extension class for each of them. And another for a different functionality. Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying?

EDIT:
In response to an answer, here is the end goal of the whole thing, since I garbled the question somewhat:

I require a way to generate dynamic proxies, similar to what Castle.DynamicProxy does in C#, in order to create a remote call concept library I'm working on. The existing Proxy class does what I require exactly, but has one fatal drawback - it requires the class to be proxied to extend Proxy, which has two downsides:
1) All the classes I need proxified need to extend proxy, which is a problem when working with existing code.
2) If an object is simply wrapped in a proxified general implementation (a class that proxies a random calasses' function calls and does something with them), the object cannot be passed to existing functions with strongly typed parameters, as it does not have the proper type (either Proxy or an extension of it are the only possible types).

Comment: How are you going to address ClassB (and its methods) if it is not "*defined at compile time*"?

Comment: ClassB would only ever have the same methods and properties as ClassA. ClassA might even be replaced by an interface, now that I think about it. So as far as the compiler is concerned, we're only ever working with ClassA instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should've shared the endpoint goal of it, because the thing you are asking for is very alien for **AS3** concepts.

Still, it is, with certain limitations, doable.

**Implementation**:

```
package assortie 
{
    public class Wrapper 
    {
        // The public interface to wrap methods.
        static public function wrap(target:Object, name:String, another:Function):void
        {
            var aWrapper:Wrapper = new Wrapper;

            // Remember the wrapped object:method.
            aWrapper.wrapped = target;
            aWrapper.wrappee = target[name];
            aWrapper.wrouter = another;

            // Substitute it with the own method.
            target[name] = aWrapper.delegateWrapper;
        }

        // A stacked list of active wrappers.
        static private var list:Array = new Array;

        // A wrapper method should call Wrapper.recall(...)
        // to invoke the wrapped method.
        static public function recall(...args:Array):*
        {
            var result:*;
            var aWrapper:Wrapper = list[list.length - 1];

            if (aWrapper)
            {
                result = aWrapper.wrappee.apply(aWrapper.wrapped, args);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private var wrapped:Object;
        private var wrappee:Function;
        private var wrouter:Function;

        private function delegateWrapper(...args:Array):*
        {
            // Register self as the last activated wrapper.
            list.push(this);

            var result:*;

            result = wrouter.apply(wrapped, args);

            // Remove self from the active wrappers' list.
            while (list.indexOf(this) > 0)
            {
                list.splice(list.indexOf(this), 1);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
package assortie 
{
    import assortie.Wrapper;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MixIn extends Sprite
    {
        public var a:int = 1;

        public function MixIn() 
        {
            // See internal class at the bottom.
            var aMix:MeexEen = new MeexEen;

            // You can stack the wrappers.
            Wrapper.wrap(this, "power", aMix.power);
            Wrapper.wrap(this, "power", aMix.power);
            Wrapper.wrap(this, "power", aMix.power);
            Wrapper.wrap(this, "power", aMix.power);
            Wrapper.wrap(this, "power", aMix.power);

            trace("The Power of Mixing In:", power());
            // Outputs:
            // 2
            // 3
            // 4
            // 5
            // 6
            // The Power of Mixing In: 720
        }

        // The method to be wrapped should be declared as variable.
        // It is not possible to replace a properly declared method.
        public var power:Function = function ():int
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

import assortie.Wrapper;

// Should be either dynamic or contain the declarations
// of all the variables accessed through "this".
internal dynamic class MeexEen
{
    // The wrapping method should be declared as closure.
    // Outherwise the method is bound to its original
    // instance and it is not possible to pass
    // another "this" to the method.
    public var power:Function = function ():int
    {
        this.a += 1;
        trace(this.a);

        return this.a * Wrapper.recall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, while you answer is not exactly what I am looking for, it gave me some insight of the workings of AS3. Specifically the comments
"// The method to be wrapped should be declared as variable.
// It is not possible to replace a properly declared method." 
gave ma a way to work around my limitations if no other way is found. If noone else suggests a better way in the next few days, your answer is pretty much my only option, and will be accepted as such.